# Ломается билд по необъяснимым причинам

Tags: javascript, webpack

2c88e невалидная лексема для js

[webpack.config.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-pond-heurp?file=/src/index.js)

По каким причинам это может быть?

[image: 2c88e невалидная лексема для js]

```
        }, 2
    c88e: (t, r, a) => {
        "use strict";
        var o, i = a(82109), u = a(31236).f, s = a(17466), v = a(3929), m = a(84488), _ = a(84964), R = a(31913),
            j = "".startsWith, M = Math.min, W = _("startsWith");
        i({
```

[issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/13010)

Comment: Тут явно не хватает скобочек. Сложно сказать почему, но скорее это проблема конкретно вашей инсталляции. Вы пробовали сделать сборку с нуля с предварительным удалением node_modules и всех уже собранных файлов?

Comment: Да, пробовал.
Это все вообще через докер запускается, так что проблема где-то в процессе сборки.
Если посмотреть все остальные id модулей, то там только числа, но здесь почему-то добавляются буквы, возможно, какое-то переполнение происходит. хз(

Comment: Ну тогда идти в https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues

Comment: Прежде чем туда идти, нужно составить [mcve], которого я тут не вижу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It's](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/) fix my problem

> If you are using webpack v5 or above you do not need to install this plugin. Webpack v5 comes with the latest terser-webpack-plugin out of the box. Using Webpack v4, you have to install terser-webpack-plugin v4.